# Pandas: Calculations across a dynamic window size associated with a column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of geolocation points (datetime, latitude, longitude) that I have labeled with the associated geohash.

```
                          
                      DATETIME   LATITUDE  LONGITUDE  GEOHASH
363446 2015-02-28 16:00:44.837  41.712755 -87.614916  dp3tq38
363428 2015-02-28 16:26:30.047  41.434128 -87.505173  dp3g8yb
363425 2015-02-28 16:30:02.659  41.421538 -87.480122  dp3g9kd
363411 2015-02-28 16:45:17.706  41.377853 -87.470677  dp3g3s9
363406 2015-02-28 16:54:50.763  41.290409 -87.467947  dp3fcse
363401 2015-02-28 17:01:21.800  41.295870 -87.439538  dp3ffm8
363373 2015-02-28 17:46:06.890  41.299363 -87.433795  dp3ffqk
363368 2015-02-28 18:07:05.769  41.299243 -87.433823  dp3ffqk
363367 2015-02-28 18:11:50.918  41.299261 -87.433823  dp3ffqk
363359 2015-02-28 18:23:33.470  41.299290 -87.433819  dp3ffqk
```

I'm looking at each *chunk* of consecutive geohashes as an independent event.  An event that I want to calculate aggregate across and calculate basic statistics for (max, min, mean).

For instance, in the dataframe above the last four rows are associated with geohash `dp3ffqk`.  The geohash `dp3ffqk` exists elsewhere in the dataframe so `groupby` seems inappropriate.  My desired output for this *chunk* of geohash `dp3ffqk` would be the duration between the minimum and maximum timestamps .

I've looked at things like `cumsum`, `rolling`, `cut` and others.  However, they all seems to imply a static window.  In my case, my window size will be dynamic.

I've tried creating an additional column `GEOHASH_` with `shift()`.  Then performing a row-wise comparison between `GEOHASH` and `GEOHASH_` and updating dictionaries when appropriate.  This was really messy.

My desired output would be a consolidation of events associated with each geohash, and statistics based on the collection of durations calculated for each.

```
  GEOHASH MAXIMUM MINIMUM AVERGAE
1 dp3ffqk     112      10   42.34
2 dp3ffm8      72      11   38.21
```

Comment: What columns are those MAX/MIN/AVG calculated on?

Comment: They wouldn't be calculated with any of the existing columns.  It be the max/min/average `duration` across all instances of consecutive geohash.

Comment: Why not include the duration column in your data? That would help to verify that our code is what you want.

Comment: Apologies as I wasn't clear.  Trying to wrap my head around how to explain it.  For each geohash `N` there are `M` chunks of consecutive rows associated with `N` spread over the dataframe.  For each chunk `M`, I want to calculate the duration spent at that geohash.  Then across the dataframe, I would calculate the min/max/average for each set of durations associated with each `N`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, even though your data doesn't show it, I imagine you want to consider only consecutive groupings of GEOHASH's.  Meaning that if the same GEOHASH showed up later, it would be considered a different group.

```
v = df.GEOHASH.values
groups = np.append(v[:-1] != v[1:], False).cumsum()
df.groupby([df.GEOHASH, groups]).agg(['min', 'max', 'mean'])

            LATITUDE                        LONGITUDE                      
                 min        max       mean        min        max       mean
GEOHASH                                                                    
dp3fcse 5  41.290409  41.290409  41.290409 -87.467947 -87.467947 -87.467947
dp3ffm8 6  41.295870  41.295870  41.295870 -87.439538 -87.439538 -87.439538
dp3ffqk 6  41.299243  41.299363  41.299289 -87.433823 -87.433795 -87.433815
dp3g3s9 4  41.377853  41.377853  41.377853 -87.470677 -87.470677 -87.470677
dp3g8yb 2  41.434128  41.434128  41.434128 -87.505173 -87.505173 -87.505173
dp3g9kd 3  41.421538  41.421538  41.421538 -87.480122 -87.480122 -87.480122
dp3tq38 1  41.712755  41.712755  41.712755 -87.614916 -87.614916 -87.614916
```

---

More involved and also not sorting the GEOHASH's

```
v = df.GEOHASH.values
groups = np.append(v[:-1] != v[1:], False).cumsum()

funcs = dict(
    LATITUDE=['min', 'max', 'mean'],
    LONGITUDE=['min', 'max', 'mean'],
    DATETIME=['min', 'max', 'count']
)

df.groupby([df.GEOHASH, groups], sort=False).agg(funcs)

            LATITUDE                        LONGITUDE                                      DATETIME                              
                 min        max       mean        min        max       mean                     min                     max count
GEOHASH                                                                                                                          
dp3tq38 1  41.712755  41.712755  41.712755 -87.614916 -87.614916 -87.614916 2015-02-28 16:00:44.837 2015-02-28 16:00:44.837     1
dp3g8yb 2  41.434128  41.434128  41.434128 -87.505173 -87.505173 -87.505173 2015-02-28 16:26:30.047 2015-02-28 16:26:30.047     1
dp3g9kd 3  41.421538  41.421538  41.421538 -87.480122 -87.480122 -87.480122 2015-02-28 16:30:02.659 2015-02-28 16:30:02.659     1
dp3g3s9 4  41.377853  41.377853  41.377853 -87.470677 -87.470677 -87.470677 2015-02-28 16:45:17.706 2015-02-28 16:45:17.706     1
dp3fcse 5  41.290409  41.290409  41.290409 -87.467947 -87.467947 -87.467947 2015-02-28 16:54:50.763 2015-02-28 16:54:50.763     1
dp3ffm8 6  41.295870  41.295870  41.295870 -87.439538 -87.439538 -87.439538 2015-02-28 17:01:21.800 2015-02-28 17:01:21.800     1
dp3ffqk 6  41.299243  41.299363  41.299289 -87.433823 -87.433795 -87.433815 2015-02-28 17:46:06.890 2015-02-28 18:23:33.470     4
```

Comment: Yep, apologies as I am struggling to try an explain it accurately.  You are correct. I want to consider each grouping of consecutive geohashes separately, and then aggregate across each grouping.

Comment: What does `v` need to be in the groups definition?  df['GEOHASH']?  I get a NameError when executing.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to include that.  It is the GEOHASH's